# Trying to find disconnected Graphs in Python

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory

I am looking to find disconnected subgraphs in Python

Take this graph as an example:
Index 0 represents node A , 1 represent B ... etc
-1 is just a place holder because this is a simple graph having no edges connecting itself.

The 5 represents the weight of the edges ( will have graphs in the future with different weights )

```
[[-1  5  5  0  0]
 [ 5 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 5  0 -1  0  5]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  5  0 -1]]
```

To look for disconnected graphs, I first created a True / False on if I have visited the edge or not. ( 0 and -1 are as default, True) which looks like this:

```
[[ True False False  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True  True]]
```

My approach to this problem is to start at any edge with a false value and start at the node represented by the rows, and go through all the possible edges connecting that node and its children's node, and so on. As I traverse along those vertices, I will mark the Boolean Matrix True as I have "visited" that edge. Once I know that I have "visited" all the edges, I know that I will have a connected subgraph.
Then I will look for another "False" in my True/False matrix and start from there looking for another disconnected graph, and continue until I fill in all the elements as True.

However, I am stuck on traversing through the edges

Here is my algorithm:

```
reducedMatrix = np.load(reducedweightmatrix)
print(reducedMatrix)
boolarray = (reducedMatrix == 0) | (reducedMatrix == -1)
print(boolarray)


def traverse(iy,visited_nodes,looped):
    #Only move to next index if there is no loop
    # already visited node?
    print("I am currently at: "+ str(iy))
    print(visited_nodes)
    print(looped)
    print("-----------------\n")
    if (iy in visited_nodes):
        looped = True
    if(not looped):
        print("I enterred the loop")
        children = []
        #Find connected "children" vertices
        for ix,weight in enumerate(reducedMatrix[iy]):
            if weight != 0 and weight != -1:
                #Collect the index with connected vertices
                children.append(ix)
                #I AM GOING TO VISIT  THESE VERTICES
                boolarray[iy,ix] = True

        print(children)
        visited_nodes.append(iy) 
        for child,children in enumerate(children):
            print(child)
            traverse(child,visited_nodes,looped)
    return visited_nodes

print(traverse(0,[],False))
```

Using the example shown above, here are the log messages:

```
[[-1  5  5  0  0]
 [ 5 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 5  0 -1  0  5]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  5  0 -1]]
[[ True False False  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True  True]]
I am currently at: 0
[]
False
-----------------

False
I enterred the loop
[1, 2]
0
I am currently at: 0
[0]
False
-----------------

True
1
I am currently at: 1
[0]
False
-----------------

False
I enterred the loop
[0]
0
I am currently at: 0
[0, 1]
False
-----------------

True
[0, 1]
```

According to the example above, the algorithm should be showing the following: 
[0,1,2,4]
Please point out to me where I went wrong with the recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand this piece of code,

```
for child,children in enumerate(children):
    print(child)
    traverse(child,visited_nodes,looped)
```

Just change it to,

```
for child in children:
    print(child)
    traverse(child,visited_nodes,looped)
```

The answer is right over there.

What you want is to visit every child in the children, not the index of children. What you saved in `children` previously is the index number. You definite do not want to find the index of index number.

**Edit**: If you are iterating over an iterable, please don't name your value the same as the iterable itself. Guess what happens below?

```
children = list(range(10))  
for child,children in enumerate(children):
    pass
print(children)
```